# Svg element hiding if is out of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I want to move a `svg element` outside of it's `container` but is hiding. I enabled `overflow: visible` still can't figured out the problem.

I created the svg with  figma. `Clip content` is disabled

Here you have the [code](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/ce69113723a910d541e6eb154409ed2c) & a [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sislB.jpg) to better see the problem.

Comment: Try `x="-100"  width="200%"`  for the filter `#filter0_f`

Comment: Hmm so i just need to increase the `width` & `height` of the frame in figma?

Answer (score 0):

This SVG code might be helpful... Open this Snippet in full view..

```css
/** Animation Boxes (Moving on cursor move) **/
.showcase-animation-container {
 position: absolute;
 right: 350px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;

 svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: visible !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
}

.left-triangle { transform-origin: center center }

.left-triangle {
 transform: translate(-180px, -70px) rotate(-50deg);
 fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="showcase-animation-container">
 <svg width="736" height="589" viewBox="-80 0 556 589" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_f)" style="
   /* margin-left: 180px; */
   ">
   <path class="left-triangle" d="M12.6269 323.5L130 82.9806L247.373 323.5H12.6269Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="7"></path>
   <path d="M389.373 265.5L272 506.019L154.627 265.5H389.373Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="7"></path>
   <path d="M308.627 323.5L426 82.9806L543.373 323.5H308.627Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="7"></path>
  </g>
  <defs>
   <filter id="filter0_f" x="-180" y="-7" width="736" height="589" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"></feBlend>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur"></feGaussianBlur>
   </filter>
  </defs>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the svg element, you can check it in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/ce69113723a910d541e6eb154409ed2c), i just increased the `frame size` in `figma`.